# jQuery promises and deferreds vs rsvp.js

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, rsvp.js

I have been trying to understand the concept of promises implemention by jQuery and deferreds. I also started reading about rsvp.js, which says they are promises/A+ compliant whereas jQuery promises are not. Can someone guide me to a book / online resource or example which can help me in getting to know the advantages of rsvp.js over jQuery promises. I am so confused after going through different tutorials.

Comment: There is a close reason on SO that clearly state that *"questions asking us to recommend or find a **book**, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow."*

Comment: See also [this old (now deleted) answer of mine](http://smm.zoomquiet.io/data/20130921230730/index.html)